# Cannot access array within an object I sent from my node server

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I sent over a JSON object from my node server, and i receiving it on my front end, but i cannot access the content, which is a HTML file that i want to display in a DIV, for educational purposes i am using pure java script.

i posted a picture of my XHR response coming through, and i can see the object but i cant display the content of it, please help!

**This is what i have on my back end:**

```
app.post('/searchDB', function(req, res) {
  var Tutorial = require("./server/models/tutorial")

  Tutorial.find({
    content: new RegExp(req.body.term, "i")
  }).exec(function(error, tutorials) {

    console.log(tutorials)
    // var searchContent = tutorials
    // res.end(tutorials)
    res.json({
      searchresults: tutorials
    })

  })
})
```

**This is what i have catching it on my front end,** the console log is displaying the oject which is search data, this is my first time asking stackO a questions so i am new, sorry if i am not explaining correctly.

**Front end code:**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open("POST", "/searchDB", true)
// set a variable equal to the form data variable 
var fd = new FormData()
fd.append("term", content)
//now send input value to our server in fd variable
xhr.send(fd)

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

    //- console.log(xhr.responseText)
    searchData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)

    //- console.log(searchData)
    console.log("the following object has been received from the server:")
    console.log(searchData)
```

Comment: Are there more lines to the front end code? You don't seem to be closing your `onreadystatechange` function declaration.

Comment: You also aren't putting the `searchData` anywhere for it to be visible. If you use jQuery -- and assuming a div with ID of `dataGoesHere` exists on your HTML -- you could do something like `$('#dataGoesHere').html(searchData);` -- or without jQuery (more verbose, though for *just this* jQ is a little overkill) -- `document.getElementById('dataGoesHere').innerHtml = searchData;`